# Woocommerce add to cart button missing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

if you go to this page and try to make a selection, you can see that the add to cart button isn't showing up. http://www.wearigive.com/product/camo-bracelet/

you can see all of the comments on this page: http://www.woothemes.com/2012/08/in-this-weeks-episode-of-woocommerce/  about the add to cart button not showing

I can't figure out why the button won't show? I have verified jQuery 1.7 is running in the page, and it's not being overwritten by another jQuery version.

Comment: it's because `<div class="single_variation_wrap" style="display:none;">` <-- this is hiding that whole div part

Comment: I looked through all your css/scripts but I couldn't find what was causing it.  Was it hardcoded or something?

Comment: which was useful in making the "Clear Selection" link work too

Comment: That works :)  I would have done the same for a quick fix - then troubleshoot later

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into this problem and solved it by simply filling out the needed information for the product (ID, SKU, Price, Weight, Dimensions)

[image]

Comment: I tried filling out the needed information for the product (ID, SKU, Price, Weight, Dimensions) but still can't see the show the Add to cart button.

Comment: SKU and price is enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

And sometimes this will solve the problem: 
Go to `apperience > customization > woocommerce > catalog mode` and disable it. This only works for not showing the "add to cart" button.
That was my case

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem this way once. Went to Appearance > Customize > Shop and made the Catalog mood 'Disabled'. http://yourSite.com/wp-admin/customize.php

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  My solution was simpler. Turned out I'd used a plugin that moves javascript to the bottom of the page to speed up the page loads.  Apparently that caused a jquery issue.  Disabling the plugin returned the button to visibility.

Comment: Well what's weird is it only does it in one theme and not the other. Does YOOtheme's Inspire use a plugin or anything special with JavaScript that you're aware of?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be broken. If the product has variables, and when the option to `enable AJAX add to cart buttons on product archives` in the `woocommerce` settings, the button div will be revealed to the user once all the selections are made. The reason, there may be options to choose which affect the price. In your testing, be sure to make all of the required selections on the user side.

Comment: That option doesn't affect this feature. I don't think there is a good work around.